# Reporting Services Column Groups Cell span over group

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have a report in SSRS with a column group that displays the days over the group. The column group spreads over a week; and renders a column per day (there is a single value in each day.)

[image: Report rendered with values]

The report editor view of the column

[image: report in designer]

Is there a way to have a cell span over the entire column group (so i can put a sub report into the report?

Answer (score 0):

select all of the columns, right click and then merge cells.

Comment: In the editor there is only one cell; at run time it is repeated out over the number of days of the report. What I am looking to do is put a subreport into the cell that repeats over all the matrix report's days. I have done this for now by using 3 report parts which works but doesnt look as tidy as i would like (and when you open the report in Excel looks terrible)

Comment: I didn't realize it was a growing matrix column group. Sorry about that. I don't really have any suggestions, good luck though, sorry I can't help!